# Persistent database with docker-compose in DigitalOcean

Tags: database, docker, docker-compose, digital-ocean, persistent-storage

I am running a docker-compose project in a DigitalOcean Docker droplet.

I also have a persistent volume.
It has been mounted on `/mnt/volume_fra1_01`

In my `docker-compose.yml`, I defined the volume for the database:

```
...

db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./postgres/.env

...

volumes:
  postgres_data:

...
```

and I've created the symbolic link with `sudo ln -s /mnt/volume_fra1_01 postgres_data`

But I the database is not persistent. When I purge the containers the database is gone. Somehow `/var/lib/postgresql/data/` is not using the mounted volume.

Answer (score 0):

when you write this :

```
- postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

postgres_data is a named volume. not a local folder. Is this what digital ocean told you to do ?

can you try with this :

```
- ./postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

Comment: Thanks. But this way it returns 502 Bad Gateway when trying to access the administration area (and presumably with all accesses to the database)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to configure your volumes without the symbolik link :

```
volumes:
  - /mnt/volume_fra1_01:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

Should work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it does not work: ```db: forward host lookup failed: Unknown host```